# WooCommerce: change button class without overwrite template files

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to change the button classes of WooCommerce with the classes from Bootstrap.

At the moment I've done that by overwriting the existing templates files. In many cases, the button classes are the only changes.

Is there any hook to do this for all buttons instead of overwriting the template files?

I couldn't find anything

Comment: Create a child theme  - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes. With this, you can do all changes without changing the original theme

Comment: that's what I've done already. I want to do it without a child theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about a hook for this (there could be one), and I don't know about the Bootstrap classes. But if you want to avoid overwriting template files you could achieve it with some JavaScript.

Add this code to the functions.php and it will change the class names accordingly.

But the functions.php file will be overwritten with every theme update. So the proper way would be to create a child theme.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'change_button_class' );
function change_button_class() {
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.button-1').addClass('button-2').removeClass('button-1');
    });
    </script>

    <?php
}
```

**Update**

Added script tag

Comment: Although this will work, doing this with Javascript is not the recommended way. It is also not the recommended way to add Javascript via the `wp_head` hook (you've also missed out the `<script>` tags).

Answer (score 2):

If you use Bootstrap 4 and SASS you can make it with [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend)

For example you can easily change the default `woocommerce` button to a `bootstrap` button like this:

```
.woocommerce .button {
  @extend .btn;
  @extend .btn-primary;
}
```